# Need to provide genres from themoviedb API via Retrofit

Tags: android

I am getting movie data to my list of movies.
I need to get genres in my DetailActivity with list of movie Genres.

Here is endpoint and docs.
http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/genres/genremovielist/get

I have the right POJO and interface for rest client,as well as MainActivity where i called RestAdapter.

Problem is in my DetailsActivity.I have ListView of genres, and I dont know how to setText to array and call getGenres().

Thank you.

Bellow is my POJO model class:

```
public class Genres  {    

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface MoviesApiService {

**@GET("/genre/movie/list")
void getGenreMovies (Callback<Genres> cb);**
```

}

I called Restadapter in my MainActivity:

```
private void getGenres() {
        RestAdapter.getMovieService().getGenreMovies(new Callback<Genres>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Genres genres, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
    }
```

And DetailsActiviy:

```
 private Movie mMovie;
private Reviews mReviews;
ImageView backdrop;
ImageView poster;
TextView title;
TextView description;
TextView releaseDate;
TextView voteAverage;
ListView genres;
TextView author;
TextView content;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE)) {
        mMovie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Detail activity must receive a movie parcelable");
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    toolbarLayout.setTitle(mMovie.getTitle());



    backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
    description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_description);

    releaseDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_date);
    voteAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
    author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_review);
    content  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.review_comment);
    **genres = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genresArray);**





            title.setText(mMovie.getTitle());
    description.setText(mMovie.getDescription());
    voteAverage.setText(mMovie.getVoteAverage());
    releaseDate.setText(mMovie.getReleaseDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish.
for a start try getting an instance of your Genre class.
then getting the id or what ever method you need from there.
you'll need to create a custom adapter and pass the names gotten from the Genre class to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the callback returns Genres POJO. It is a list of containing Genre POJOs.
Rename your **Genres** POJO to **Genre** and you need to create an additional POJO

```
public class Genres{
    public List<Genre> genres;
}
```

and in your success call use this code snippet.

```
final List<Genre> resultGenres = response.body().genres;
```

There you have your returned genres and I guess you would pass this list to the DetailActivity.